# How to set the path for cairo in ubuntu-12.04?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, pycairo

I need to install pycairo with python3.2+.But I have error when installing the pycairo in my system,

```
Downloading/unpacking git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Cloning http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo to /tmp/pip-ud145u-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Failed
    Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'cairo' found

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Failed

Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'cairo' found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install `libcairo2-dev` first:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```